# Replace Wordpress Searching Function

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, search, plugins

I recently installed a plugin named WP Google Search on my Wordpress.
This plugin allows you to create a widget with a custom search engine powered by google.

What I am trying to understand is, how to override the original Wordpress searching function by replacing it with the custom google search?

Thank you in advance,

Fred.